# Adding dependency causes gradle project sync failed

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Attempting to use google map in my app in Android Studio.  Following steps for 'Set up project that uses google play services' and the step where I add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```

**build.gradle file :**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
           runProguard false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

 }


 dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
 }
```

and then I selected 'Sync project with Gradle files' from toolbar

and I get 'Gradle project sync failed.

log cat:

> 02-26 11:04:22.139    3502-3502/com.android.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
>   02-26 11:04:22.202    3502-3502/com.android.app E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
>   02-26 11:04:22.335    3502-3502/com.android.app D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
>   02-26 11:04:22.350    3502-3502/com.android.app D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
>   02-26 11:04:22.350    3502-3502/com.android.app D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
>   02-26 11:04:22.460    3502-3502/com.android.app D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
>   02-26 12:50:29.960    3502-3507/com.android.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
>   02-26 13:01:02.467    3502-3507/com.android.app D/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

Event log:

> 1:02:53 PM Gradle 'Test' project refresh failed:
>              A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>              : Gradle settings
>   1:10:38 PM Gradle 'Test' project refresh failed:
>              A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>              : Gradle settings
>   1:12:19 PM Gradle 'Test' project refresh failed:
>              Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.
>              Unable to start the daemon process.
>              This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
>              For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
>              Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>              Please read below process output to find out more:
>              -----------------------
>              Error occurred during initialization of VM
>              Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>              Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>              Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>              : Gradle settings
>   1:12:26 PM Gradle 'Test' project refresh failed:
>              A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>              : Gradle settings

I removed the line and I'm still stuck with the error.

I have been attempting to use google maps android api v2 for weeks now.  After giving up on eclipse I'm now trying in AS and its nothing but pulling teeth every step of the way.  How is anybody getting this to work...seriously???

Comment: What version of AS? We've seen sporadic reports of issues with "Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap". It had been my theory that users seeing this just didn't have enough RAM, but I saw a case on a machine with 32GB. Does it help if you quit Android Studio and re-launch? If not, can you attach a copy of your process listing (not sure what OS you're running) so we can see if there are a bunch of the Gradle daemon processes running? If it ends up being something like that, we'll want to capture it in a bug report and take it off SO.

Comment: Windows 7 32 bit.  AS 0.4.6.  JRE 1.7.0_45-b18 x86.  I've closed and reopened. EDIT: Just restarted everything one last time and error went away.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with the fact that you're running 32-bit Widnows instead of 64-bit. I don't know for sure how that would affect this.